# Mac Excel Vs Windows Excel | Print Preview is not consistent

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, print-preview

I have one excel file with 17 Columns created using Windows Excel.
Print Size: A3

When i see print preview in **Windows Excel (2010)** (First Page covers upto 12 colums)
[image]

Same file, i opened in **MacOS Excel (16.39 20071300)** (First Page covers upto 11 colums)
[image]

Is there anything changed in rendering page size for different OS?

Comment: Printer margin setup?

Comment: @Tetsujin its same(Normal) in Both Machine. e.g. 0.75,0.75,0.7,0.7

Answer (score 0):

The main reason may be that fonts do not match, and different fonts may have different placeholders in paragraphs.

In addition, the default templates are set differently in different systems.

Please make sure that the paper has the same default margin.

If you can't find the real cause, you can set up the print area:

page layout - print area

Comment: I am using exact same excel file in both system so font and margin is same.

setting a print area works but i do not want to tell end user to do any steps.